# Python: How to Create chucks of data contain X byte for each time

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to write a simple function that take a data in hex format. However, the idea is I want to use for loop with round() so that each time the loop will print only 2KB (2048) of data (only 2048 byte for each time),

This is what I did, but did not work.

```
data = "4d5a90000300000004000000fff........"

def function_x(x):
    for i in range(0,int(round(len(data)/2048))):
        data_chunk = data[i*2047:(i+1)*2047]
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
```

**UPDATE:** To make my question clear for you, I will provide some details. I am using Postgresql, Large objects specifically, However, to update this object or insert any new data on it, you must keep this note in you mind, which is mentioned in their documentation

> The amount of data per page is defined to be LOBLKSIZE (which is currently BLCKSZ/4, or typically 2 kB "2048").

so I wrote this simple code to fit with their requirements, just do not know what is the the right numbers must be written instead of (?) marks that i put

`for i in range(0,int(round(len(data)/??))):`  > to divide the code into x number of pages, each page must contain 2048 byte only > `data[i*??:(i+1)*??]`

**NOTE:** `if i == 0` because the first page must be updated not inserted according to their docs

**here is the full code**

```
data = "4d5a90000300000004000000fff........"
loid = 14697

def function_x(x):
        for i in range(0,int(round(len(data)/??))):
    data_chunk = data[i*??:(i+1)*??]
    if i == 0:
        sql = "UPDATE PG_LARGEOBJECT SET data=decode('%s', 'hex') where loid=%d and pageno=%d" % (data_chunk, loid, i)
    else:
        sql = "INSERT PG_LARGEOBJECT SET data=decode('%s', 'hex') where loid=%d and pageno=%d" % (data_chunk, loid, i)
        ....
        ....
        ....
        ....
```

Comment: `for i in range(0,len(data), 2048)`? The last variable in `range` is `step`. You may need to hold the previous value in a buffer.

Comment: What's 2047? I'd suggest you write down the values for different `len(data)` manually first and then start to code this. I think it will become obvious then. As a new user, also take the [tour] and read [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A list comprehension would fit. The code below will create a list with all of the chunks and then print them one by one.

```
chunks = [data[i:i+2048] for i in range(0, len(data), 2048)]
print(*chunks, sep='\n')
```

You could also turn this into a single line (se below), but I prefer the method above, since it's easier to understand what is happening.

```
print(*[data[i:i+2048] for i in range(0, len(data), 2048)], sep='\n')
```

**UPDATE:**
If you want to check things about the list items, you could simply do this:

```
for i, chunk in enumerate([data[i:i+2048] for i in range(0, len(data), 2048)]):
  if i == 0:
    ...
  else:
    ...
```

I hope I understood the update question and that this will help.

Comment: I have updated the post to add more details about the issue, thank you for your contribution :)

Comment: Ok. Doesn’t my solution work for you? If not, I’ll take a second look soon and see if I find a solution :)

Comment: Thank you for your time, yes doesn't solve the problem.

Comment: I updated the answer. If I understood the question, this should work

Answer (score 0):

```py
data = "4d5a90000300000004000000fff........"

def function_x(x):
    while x != "":
        data_chunk = x[0:2048]
        # Do some stuff with data_chunk
        x = x[2048:]
        ...
        ...
```

Comment: I have updated the post to add more details about the issue, thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `islice` from `itertools` module:

```
from itertools import islice

a = '4d5a90000300000004000000fff'
length = 5

data = iter(a)
while True:
    elm = list(islice(data, length))
    if not elm:
        break
    print(elm)
```

Output:

```
['4', 'd', '5', 'a', '9']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '3']
['0', '0', '0', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '4', '0', '0']
['0', '0', '0', '0', 'f']
['f', 'f']
```

Comment: I have updated the post to add more details about the issue, thank you for your contribution :)

Answer (score 0):

This Solved my problem too.

```
    # divide the length by 2048 to create pages on that range (PostGresql things)
    for i in range(0,int(round(len(data)/2048))):
    # Here will guarantee to take only 2048 byte without any repeat in the data
    data_chunk = data[i*2048:(i+1)*2048]
```